# Does replacing $(this) with a variable make any performance difference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
$('#SomeSelectorID').find('.SomeElementsByClassName').each(function () {

    $(this).some code here;
    $(this).some other code there;
    $(this).some other code here and there;
});
```

If I write at the top of the loop `var TheThis = $(this);` and then replace `$(this)` with `TheThis` is that a performance optimization or not really?

Comment: Some say it is, some say it is'nt. My opinion is that it used to make sense, but these days browsers does such a good job that the `this` keyword is probably cached somehow anyway, so in most cases you'll never notice a difference.

Comment: Can you measure it? If yes *and it's on a critical path* the it might be worth it. If not then your time is far more valuable than an intrusive change which might lead to regressions for no benefit.

Comment: @adeneo It doesn't matter if the browser caches `this`, the problem is with caching `$(this)`

Comment: Perhaps you should ask how to optimize the code you have, instead of asking if a specific optimization is worth it. (The `.each` loop you have there can be accomplished in native JavaScript and will doubtless be faster that way.) Dollars to donuts there are better optimizations available here than just `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: @ian - You don't really cache a selector when using `var something = $(this)`, as  the `this` keyword is probably cached locally anyway. all you really do is avoid a function call by saving the result of that function call to a variable, and unless it's a very inefficient function, and `$()` is'nt, it does'nt really save you that much. IMO it depends on how many times you intend to use that particular `this`, if it's once or twice, I would just use `this`.

Comment: any reason you can't just chain the functions? `$(this).someCodeHere().someOtherCodeThere().someOtherCodeHereAndThere();`

Comment: @adeneo I don't understand your point. It doesn't matter if the element(s) are "cached", the fact that every time you call `$(this)`, it requires the creation of a jQuery object, is the point. `this` is a reference to a DOM element, so jQuery doesn't have to go look in the DOM, but there's still processing for using `$()` no matter what. You're right that it also depends on how often in the function `$(this)` would be used

Comment: @ian - You could probably call the `$()` function billions of times a second when passing it `this`, as that would just immediately return the object, no extra stuff needed, so the performace gains are almost immeasurable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a definite performance optimisation. One you'll probably not notice, but that's no reason not to do it.

The code in your example means that the DOM will be interrogated 3 times to look for the `$(this)` element and then perform the actions on it. Caching it in a variable means that that will only occur once.

If you really want to see the difference try comparing your original with the below in a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com) test.

```
$('#SomeSelectorID').find('.SomeElementsByClassName').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.some code here;
    $this.some other code there;
    $this.some other code here and there;
});
```

Comment: There should be no "DOM interrogation" in this case.  `this` is a DOM element which is being passed to `jQuery()`.  It doesn't need to look it up.  It is an unneeded call to a function though.

Comment: @JamesMontagne good point for this particular case. However it is always good practice to cache the result of a selector, passed or otherwise IMO.

Comment: Right, the only reason this is even debatable is because it is `this`.  If it were a selector instead of `this` there is no question that it's a performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** there is a performance penalty. I've created a small demo that illustrates using $(this) is slower than using a stored version of it.

JSFiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7894E/2/).

**No** I don't think you need to change your code. The benefit in this case will be so small that you will hardly notice any difference. Maybe in another situation where you are developing a game or data processing app it can matter.

Here are the results of my test...

```
Testing jquery version...
1000000 iterations $(this): 0.006849ms
Testing non-jquery version...
1000000 iterations of this$: 0.001356ms
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is a performance optimization. Whether it is worth it or not, that's the real question. If you are reiterating over the DOM then it would definitely be worth it. In this case, you are just wrapping an object in jQuery so the footprint is much smaller.

That being said, you gain a little bit of performance but lose nothing in terms of readability, maintainability, or other things that you usually have to sacrifice to gain performance, so you may as well make the tweak.

Comment: I guess the reason I'm asking is that I have about 14K lines of javascript to go through and I'm wondering if it's worth doing.

Comment: @frenchie it boils down to this: you gain a little and lose nothing, so why not?

Comment: *"Of course it is a performance optimization"* - not if the function can be proved to be pure, in which case it probably adds no extra cost. Even if nobody does it today doesn't mean nobody will tomorrow.

Comment: @frenchie if you have 14k lines it is definitely worth doing and will probably make a big difference if you've not cached any selectors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan keep in mind there is a huge difference between caching `$(this)` and caching something like `$('#someSelector')` - the latter jQuery func you would **definitely** want to store.

Comment: @jbabey: I'm already optimizing $('#someSelector') inside my functions if the selector needs to be accessed more than once; here I'm just talking about optimizing $(this) when it's inside a jquery loop.

Comment: @jbabey - I disagree with "lose nothing" - firstly in 14k LOC that's probably big enough that the odds of introducing defects are non-negligible and secondly even if you don't introduce a defect the time it takes to do something that hasn't even been measured isn't free and detracts from other areas where the time might be better invested.

Comment: @Flexo generally human effort is not considered when talking about code performance optimizations :P

Comment: Which is exactly why people waste years of effort doing pointless "optimisations" that win nothing.

Comment: And then it depends on how many scopes there are in those 14k lines of codes, and how many times each `this` is used within it's scope etc.

Comment: @Flexo You're right, because reducing 10 `$()` calls in a `mousemove` callback wouldn't optimize anything. Yeah...

Comment: @Ian a) OP didn't mention where it is, if it's a timer that fires once per hour it certainly would be wasted effort. b) if the redraw/reflow after the callback accounts for 99% of the time then shaving 0.1% off the remaining 1% of the time is negligible and like trying to empty an ocean with a teacup. The point is that *changing* anything in existing code without a concrete profile and way more than just a hunch is wasted effort.

Answer (score 1):

Testing this shows no performance impact, at least on Chrome:

```
var start = new Date().getTime(),
    iterations = 50000;

$('#foo').find('.bar').each(function () {

    var that = $(this);

    for(var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
      that.find('i');

});

console.log(new Date().getTime() - start);
```

Using `$(this)` results are more or less the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/BuREW/

Comment: Something interesting though: Opera appears to traverse the DOM 10 times slower than IE and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Well, duh.

In general, calling any function is an expense. Calling `$()` is a HUGE one (compare calling times compared to [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/)) and one that should be avoided as much as possible.

Storing its return value in a variable is always a good thing, but it also avoids certain "gotchas".

For instance, let's say you want to change all `.test` elements to green and remove the class. You might do this:

```
$(".test").removeClass("test");
$(".test").css({"color":"green"});
```

Only to find that it doesn't change the colour to green because `$(".test")` isn't the same thing anymore.

Conversely, if you had done:

```
var test = $(".test");
test.removeClass("test");
test.css({"color":"green"});
```

It works. Of course, this is a trivial example since you can just rearrange the code lines and it works too, but I'm triyng to make a point here :p

Comment: This is all true, but does not apply to the question specifically.  `$()` is by no means "HUGE" when you're calling it passing `this`.  It's pretty small.   I do love that link though.